# Primary domain controller has crashed, and exchange 2010 don't find the secondary?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

Primary domain controller has crashed, and exchange 2010 don't find the secondary one!

I also promote the secondary to Primary but still nothing.
Mistakenly restarted the Exchange server and now I have nothing (no Management Console, no Management Shell).

Is there any file to edit and specify correct DC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this command "NLTest /DSGetSite" I just solved the problem.
thanks for reply

Answer (score 3):

No such thing as primary and secondary domain controllers. All domain controllers are equal.

Exchange should find the domain controller automatically. Ensure the DNS within the OS is configured correctly and that the second domain controller is also a global catalog.

If the original DC has gone away (so cannot be recovered) then you will need to seize the FSMO roles. After doing that, clean up the domain to remove the domain controller properly.

Once you have seized the FSMO roles, checked DNS and global catalog, reboot the Exchange server again and the services should start.

Comment: Thanks for reply. where should i set the DNS ! Which one OS you mean?

Comment: The secondary is as GC.

Comment: about the FSMO! how can i connect to server when its already gone! (I tried FSMO using this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816779(v=ws.10).aspx) )

Comment: The second domain controller should have DNS on it, so set the Exchange server should be set to use that as the DNS server. 

Seizing the roles is specifically designed for the scenario of the failed domain controller. Try these instructions instead. 
https://www.briandesmond.com/active-directory/how-to-seize-a-fsmo-role-with-ntdsutil/

Comment: I've done Seizing the PDC.

Comment: but steel don't get the how set the DNS !? Is there any link out there to show me the way ?

Comment: I just set the DomainName in the IPV4 advanced properties box : "DNS suffix for this connection" and restart the exchange server.

Comment: event viewer log:  The Microsoft Exchange Throttling Service encountered an Active Directory error while building an RPC security descriptor. This failure may indicate that no Domain Controllers are available at this time. The service will be stopped. Failure details: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.NoSuitableServerFoundException: The Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology service on server localhost did not return any suitable domain controllers.

Comment: Process MAD.EXE (PID=2412). Topology discovery failed, error 0x80040920 (LDAP_NO_SUCH_OBJECT). Look up the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) error code specified in the event description. To do this, use Microsoft Knowledge Base article 218185, "Microsoft LDAP Error Codes." Use the information in that article to learn more about the cause and resolution to this error. Use the Ping or PathPing command-line tools to test network connectivity to local domain controllers.